# benefit of using rspec .to eq() syntax with expect()

Tags: ruby, rspec

I got a warning about rspec's .should method becoming depreciated, and found the newer "expect" syntax. Playing around with a simple example I saw that there seem to be a couple options:

```
it("should be named 'ruby'") do
  expect(thing.name).to eq('ruby')
end
```

or

```
it ("should be named 'ruby'") do
  expect(thing.name == 'ruby')
end
```

And it seems that if you were looking to do a comparison that you can only do the second option anyway:

```
it ("should be smaller than 5") do
  expect(thing.amount < 5)
end
```

This is my first forage into rspec, or even testing really. Why have the .to eq() syntax at all?

Comment: You can write `expect(thing.amount).to be < 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `expect(thing.name == 'ruby')` is even valid. If you want to test for less than or greater than you can do this:

```
it ("should be smaller than 5") do
  expect(thing.amount).to be < 5
end
```

The benefit of being explicit like this is that rspec can give you much better error messages because it knows exactly what it's checking for instead of "the following expression should be true"